# Login failed using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl

```
$username = 'myname';
$password = 'mypass';
$loginUrl = 'https://example.com/login/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content;
```

I'm seeing the login instead of the secured content after login. What has gone wrong in my case?

Comment: Technically the `$username` and `$password` would have to be URL-encoded before sending them. If they contain non-URL-safe characters that is going to make a difference. But I would check your server-side code: does it really have a form with `user` and `pass` fields (or perhaps `username` and `password`).

Comment: @HansZ. for the password part should I just put a string? like 'abc', should I hash them with MD5 or just put 'abc'?

Comment: @HansZ. I'm logging in others' site, how can I know what param they pass?

Comment: impossible to tell without looking at the form presented by `/login/` itself.

Comment: @HansZ. I found it.. but now it returned blank..

Comment: check what happens using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and you may also have to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to follow redirects

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); gave me the original unlogined page, while echo curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); returned 1

Comment: Check the logs on the server that executes the php script.

Answer (score 1):

Either the login page expects something else except user and pass variables(e.g. it might check for user agent, or more variables), or data is not properly encoded, you can use following code to encode the strings properly:

```
$data = array(
    'user' => $username,
    'pass' => $password
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

To check what variables they expect you have to use some kind of network sniffer, e.g. in Chrome Developer Tools you can open Network tab and check what data login form sends.

Or you can post that URL here and I will check that for you. You can send me an email to mstrokin at gmail.com if you don't want to post it here.

Comment: thanks but now it returned blank, does that mean my username and password is wrong? hmm

Comment: it could be anything..Drop me an email with the login URL and I'll check it. Blank page usually means that there's a redirect (use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow that redirect), but if you get original unlogined page then it means you don't pass correct form data to the login URL